# How do I overwrite an existing application image (png) file in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to have an image as part of my apk that the user can modify using my app.
I dont want to save it on the SD card. It should not be viewable or editable outside the app.

Where do I need to put the original image, the one I include to be used by default? 
In the resources drawble folder? Or the assets folder?

And how do I overwrite that image with a user-generated one? (with the idea that this will be used in the app everywhere instead.)

Answer (score 1):

- You cannot overwrite resources not assets contents.
- Alternative solution:
  What about saving it to the internal directory of an application, which would not be accessible outside of you application scope? and then every time you display a picture, check if the one in internal memory exists, if it does, then display that one instead of the one in drawables

docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

> You can save files directly on the device's internal storage. By
>   default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your
>   application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the
>   user). When the user uninstalls your application, these files are
>   removed.

Comment: So is your suggestion, I include the image as an asset, then on app startup - if I haven't copied that image to internal storage, do it, then load that?

Comment: @PlasticSturgeon Algorithm :) : 1. Put image in drawables. 2. Load image from drawables if you cannot find an image (maybe with the same name as your drawable) from internal storage. 3. If you can find an image (maybe with the same name as your drawable) then display image from internal storage

Comment: and then overwriting is as simple as using the same file name for the local storage file? Let me go test this out.